# How to draw a stack of rectangles with a predefined start position and margin level in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[The JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sachid/sLu82bom/4/) of this.

I want a neat stack of svg rectangles when the starting position and the vertical margin is defined and use data from an array.

In the JSfiddle, the output container is manually coded to demonstrate the desired result. How to get it using d3? I have tried the following.

```
            var inputs = [{"text": "inleaf1","col":"red"}, {"text": "inleaf2","col":"blue"}, {"text": "inleaf3","col":"green"}];

            var elementwidth = 120;
            var elementheight = 50;
            var inputstartx = 20;
            var inputstarty=20; ///////////y should change for each rectangle
            var verticalmargin = 20;

            var canvas = d3.select(".canvas");
            var inputcontainer = d3.select("#input-container");


            var inputleaf = inputcontainer
                    .data(inputs)
                    .enter().append("rect")
                    .attr("class","input-leaf")
                    .attr("width",elementwidth)
                    .attr("height",elementheight)
                    .attr("x",inputstartx)
                    .attr("y",function(d,i){
                        return Number(inputstarty)+(elementheight*i)+verticalmargin;
                    })
                    .attr("stroke",function(d){
                        return d.col;
                    });
```

Comment: you are already doing this calculation to place the rectangle `return Number(inputstarty)+(elementheight*i)+verticalmargin;` this is how you do in d3...are you asking for something else?

Comment: Well it's not working so I thought it was wrong. Can you point me where the fault lies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are only messing this --> `selectAll()`

```js
var inputs = [{"text": "inleaf1","col":"red"}, {"text": "inleaf2","col":"blue"}, {"text": "inleaf3","col":"green"}];

            var elementwidth = 120;
            var elementheight = 50;
            var inputstartx = 20;
            var inputstarty=20; ///////////y should change for each rectangle
            var verticalmargin = 20;

            var canvas = d3.select(".canvas");
            var inputcontainer = d3.select("#input-container");


            var inputleaf = inputcontainer.selectAll('.rect')
                    .data(inputs)
                    .enter().append("rect")
                    .attr("class","input-leaf")
                    .attr("fill","none")
                    .attr("width",elementwidth)
                    .attr("height",elementheight)
                    .attr("x",inputstartx)
                    .attr("y",function(d,i){
                        return elementheight * (2*i+1);
                    })
                    .attr("stroke",function(d){
                        return d.col;
                    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg class="canvas" width="1000" height="500">
 <g id="input-container"></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: It's correct. But do you know why my method to obtain vertical position does not work?

Comment: your function  is already working you can keep it but this function :`return Number(inputstarty)+(elementheight*i)+verticalmargin;` will return respectively 40,90,140 like this there will be no spacing between your svg rectangles ... you can try `return Number(inputstarty)+(elementheight * (2*i)) + verticalmargin;`  I have only edited the function to get exactly the same y-attributes as you asked before.